# reversing order of CSS transitions

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a menu button, and a hidden list. I'm toggling classes to create a drop-down effect.

When the classes are added, it opens the drop-down just fine.

However on the removal of the classes, as you'll see in the following code snippet, the transition isn't as seamless. Basically what I'd like to do is reverse the order the transitions happen in, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks for the help.

```js
$('.contact-menu-button').children('svg').click(function (event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
  $('.contact-menu-items').toggleClass('show');
  $('.contact-menu-button').children('svg').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:200,400);

* {
  font-family: Kanit, sans-serif;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4a7ff7;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.active-contact {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.contact-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.contact-menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.contact-menu-button > svg {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    stroke: #fff;
    transition: transform 250ms linear, border-radius 250ms ease-in 275ms;
}

.contact-menu-button > svg:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  stroke: #4a7ff7;
}

.contact-menu-button > svg:active {
    stroke: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

.contact-menu-button > .rotate {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.contact-menu-button > .rotate:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.contact-menu-items {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(-57px, -6px);
    transition: visibility 250ms ease-out 550ms, height 250ms ease-out 550ms;
}

.contact-menu-items > li {
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
}

.contact-menu-items.show {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 50px;
}

.contact-menu-items > li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="active-contact">
    John Smith
  </div>
  <div class="contact-menu">
    <button class="contact-menu-button">
      <svg>
        <path d="M4 9 l 6 5 l 6 -5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="contact-menu-items">
      <li>
        <a>Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the transition times both on the base and the transformed state:

```js
$('.contact-menu-button').children('svg').click(function (event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
  $('.contact-menu-items').toggleClass('show');
  $('.contact-menu-button').children('svg').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:200,400);

* {
  font-family: Kanit, sans-serif;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4a7ff7;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.active-contact {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.contact-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.contact-menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.contact-menu-button > svg {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    stroke: #fff;
    transition: transform 250ms linear 275ms, border-radius 250ms ease-in 0ms;
}

.contact-menu-button > svg:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  stroke: #4a7ff7;
}

.contact-menu-button > svg:active {
    stroke: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

.contact-menu-button > .rotate {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: transform 250ms linear, border-radius 250ms ease-in 275ms;
}

.contact-menu-button > .rotate:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.contact-menu-items {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(-57px, -6px);
    transition: visibility 250ms ease-out, height 250ms ease-out;
}

.contact-menu-items > li {
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
}

.contact-menu-items.show {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 50px;
    transition: visibility 250ms ease-out 550ms, height 250ms ease-out 550ms;
}

.contact-menu-items > li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="active-contact">
    John Smith
  </div>
  <div class="contact-menu">
    <button class="contact-menu-button">
      <svg>
        <path d="M4 9 l 6 5 l 6 -5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="contact-menu-items">
      <li>
        <a>Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well that was easy :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch event from the button, not the SVG within ;)

```js
$('.contact-menu-button').click(function (event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
  $('.contact-menu-items').toggleClass('show');
  $('.contact-menu-button').children('svg').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:200,400);

* {
  font-family: Kanit, sans-serif;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4a7ff7;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.active-contact {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.contact-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.contact-menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.contact-menu-button > svg {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    stroke: #fff;
    transition: transform 250ms linear, border-radius 250ms ease-in 275ms;
}

.contact-menu-button > svg:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  stroke: #4a7ff7;
}

.contact-menu-button > svg:active {
    stroke: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

.contact-menu-button > .rotate {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.contact-menu-button > .rotate:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.contact-menu-items {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(-57px, -6px);
    transition: visibility 250ms ease-out 550ms, height 250ms ease-out 550ms;
}

.contact-menu-items > li {
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
}

.contact-menu-items.show {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 50px;
}

.contact-menu-items > li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="active-contact">
    John Smith
  </div>
  <div class="contact-menu">
    <button class="contact-menu-button">
      <svg>
        <path d="M4 9 l 6 5 l 6 -5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="contact-menu-items">
      <li>
        <a>Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```